# Security for webapp and rest services with spring

Tags: rest, spring-security, tapestry

First of all, let me thank you a lot for the great help you give in this site!

Well, I will go right to the point: I am a newbie in spring and I have used appfuse for creating a new web app. The initial idea was to create a simple platform with a frontend and then, invoke the rest services from an external client.

The point is that I cannot be able to define a security.xml file in which (pages and rest services), can use different authentication methods.

My idea was a login form for the pages and a authenticator based on url params for the services, but the only thing I get is an Exception:

```
A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored"
```

I have tried each one of them separately, but when I gathered them in the same file, the exception is rised.

```
 <http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/styles*/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/scripts*/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/assets*/**" security="none"/>   
    <http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
      <intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
      <custom-filter ref="myFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
      <logout />
   </http>
    <beans:bean id="myFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
      <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
      <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="mySuccessHandler"/>
   </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="org.bringer.webapp.authentication.MyAuthSuccessHandler"/>    
    <http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/accessdenied">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/passwordhint*/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/signup*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login" 
                    default-target-url="/home" 
                    always-use-default-target="true"  
                    authentication-failure-url="/login/error" 
                    login-processing-url="/j_security_check"/>                    
        <remember-me user-service-ref="userDao" key="e37f4b31-0c45-11dd-bd0b-0800200c9a66"/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
                <salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
            </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>   
    <beans:bean id="saltSource" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource"
        p:userPropertyToUse="username"/>   
    <global-method-security>
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* *..service.UserManager.getUsers(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* *..service.UserManager.removeUser(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    </global-method-security>
```

Even I have removed the "/**" pattern, but I get nothing but the exception.

Might someone point me in the right direction, please? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

This is the security.xml that helped me to solve it

```
    <http pattern="/services/**" create-session="stateless">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>
    <http pattern="/login*/**" security="none"/>    
    <http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/accessdenied">       
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/passwordhint*/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/signup*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login" 
                    default-target-url="/home" 
                    always-use-default-target="true"  
                    authentication-failure-url="/login/error" 
                    login-processing-url="/j_security_check"/>                    
        <remember-me user-service-ref="userDao" key="e37f4b31-0c45-11dd-bd0b-0800200c9a66"/>
    </http>
```